# How to use unordered bulk inserting with Mongoskin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoskin

I'm having trouble using Mongoskin to perform bulk inserting (MongoDB 2.6+) on Node.

```
var dbURI = urigoeshere;
var db = mongo.db(dbURI, {safe:true});
var bulk = db.collection('collection').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

for (var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    bulk.insert({number: i}, function() {
        console.log('bulk inserting: ', i);
    });
}

bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
    res.json('send response statement');
});
```

The above code gives the following warnings/errors:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 51 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
TypeError: Object #<SkinClass> has no method 'execute'
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 51 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
TypeError: Object #<SkinClass> has no method 'execute'
```

Is it possible to use Mongoskin to perform unordered bulk operations? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it but you need to change your calling conventions to do this as only the "callback" form will actually return a collection object from which the `.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` method can be called. There are also some usage differences to how you think this works:

```js
var dbURI = urigoeshere;
var db = mongo.db(dbURI, {safe:true});
db.collection('collection',function(err,collection) {
    var bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
        bulk.insert({number: i});
        count++;

        if ( count % 1000 == 0 )
            bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
               // maybe do something with results
               bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); // reset after execute
            });      

    });

    // If your loop was not a round divisor of 1000
    if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
        bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
          // maybe do something here
        });
});
```

So the actual "Bulk" methods themselves don't require callbacks and work exactly as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/). The exeception is `.execute()` which actually sends the statements to the server.

While the driver will sort this out for you somewhat, it probably is not a great idea to queue up too many operations before calling execute. This basically builds up in memory, and though the driver will only send in batches of 1000 at a time ( this is a server limit as well as the complete batch being under 16MB ), you probably want a little more control here, at least to limit memory usage.

That is the point of the modulo tests as shown, but if memory for building the operations and a possibly really large response object are not a problem for you then you can just keep queuing up operations and call `.execute()` once.

The "response" is in the same format as given in the documentation for [BulkWriteResult](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/).

Comment: the paging of bulks will not work as expected since you're replacing the referenc to the bulk variable in a callback that will get executed at a later point in time, so your loop will move past the first 1000 iterations and still mantain a reference to the first bulk op

Comment: I am seeing problems with mongodb 3.x and mongoskin 2.2.0 with the method suggested by Neil Lunn, I didn't know if I should re-ask this question separately or not so I created a new SO question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810387/mongoskin-and-bulk-operations-mongodb-3-2-mongoskin-2-1-0-2-2-0

Comment: Just to clarify Neil Lunn's answer, mongoskin simply doesn't support the abstractions necessary to implement bulk operations at this time.  However, there is a simple method to bypass things and go direct to the native mongojs interface if you don't want to re-code things.  It makes use of private data inside mongoskin so is not ideal, but it /does/ work...  see the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810387/mongoskin-and-bulk-operations-mongodb-3-2-mongoskin-2-1-0-2-2-0 but the short answer is, from a mongoskin db object, you can get the native object from db._native